# Can I deploy a Grails 4 app to Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: mysql, grails, google-cloud-platform

I have been able to run through the following Grails 3 guide for deploying a Grails application to GCP.

https://guides.grails.org/grails-google-cloud/guide/index.html

I've tried to mirror this using my own Grails 4 application but it fails when I try to access it.
`appengineDeploy` completes successfully but when I try and access the webapp URL, I get a long stacktrace which culminates in the following error;

```
Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/cj/api/io/SocketFactory
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.api.io.SocketFactory
```

I've been trying all sorts of various versions of the socket factory dependency to try and solve and redeploy but all result in the same error.
I have used various version of the j-6 connector (com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6) and my most recent attempt used the j-8 (1.0.14).

At this point it would be great to even know if what I'm trying is even possible. Java 11 support has been added quite recently and I have made the necessary config adjustments to get my app to deploy, but I cannot then access it.

Comment: Is `com.mysql.cj.api.io.SocketFactory` on your runtime classpath?

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, and actually, it wasn't! But thought that it was provided by the container until I realised the scope was _runtime_ and not _provided_. In any case, I've solved this by upgrading to version 8.0.15 of mysql-connector-java. Now I've a new problem, application appears to start (maybe twice) but when I try to access, I get a 500 response. No apparent errors and so nothing to go on. I'll have to spend some time investigating myself before I can even find a question to ask.

Comment: "But thought that it was provided by the container until I realised the scope was runtime and not provided." - If the scope was `runtime` then it should have been included in the runtime classpath.  If it weren't, I think that would require a bug in Gradle's dependency management.  Changing to `provided` wouldn't help. That just means that you expect it to be provided by your container, which apparently it isn't.

Comment: For sure, just to clarify, it _was_ `runtime`, but I _thought_ it was `provided` (my mistake) and so it absolutely _did_ need to be added to the classpath. The problem was that I only realised after a `dependency-report` that version 8 of the mysql connector was being pulled even though I was requesting 6. When I upgraded the socket factory connector to j-8, it solved the problem. I'm not sure why to be honest but I guess v8 of the connector is compatible j-8 of the socket factory connector.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to version 8 of mysql-connector-java in tandem with mysql-socket-factor-connector-j-8 appears to have made this particular issue go away (and moved me to the next).

Dependencies are as follows;

```
runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.15"
runtime "com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.0.14"
```